# Curl and Net Http Ruby

Tags: ruby

I can easily do in command line using curl:

```
curl --digest -u "user:password" [url]
```

But I'm trying to use Ruby's Net::HTTP. Is there a way that I can provide my username and password when trying to use Net::HTTP to GET API?

I tried the basic_auth method, but it doesn't work.

here is my code piece

## basic auth

```
uri = URI("https://www.commcarehq.org/a/chanderi/api/v0.4/form/?xmlns=http://openrosa.org/formdesigner/C3B60561-F631-4D4C-8611-10E975EF8B44")

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  req.basic_auth 'myusername', 'mypassword'
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

## for net::http::digestauth

```
digest_auth = Net::HTTP::DigestAuth.new

uri = URI.parse 'http://localhost:8000/'
uri.user = CGI.escape('username@mail.com')
uri.password = 'password'
h = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
res = h.request req
```

Net::HTTPBadResponse: wrong status line: ""

I'm following http://docs.seattlerb.org/net-http-digest_auth/Net/HTTP/DigestAuth.html

Comment: Define “doesn’t work”. What happened and what did you except to happen? Did you get an error message? Post your exact code and its output.

Comment: I add some information to my question

Comment: @Nich are you passing email in 'uri.user=' method?

Comment: yaya...because thats my username..@SachinSingh in order to get authorize

Comment: If you are using an email address as your username, the `@` needs to be escaped. Try using `CGI.escape my@email.com`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use:

```
#The URL
uri = URI.parse("http://lab")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
#Request URL
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
#Basic authentication
request.basic_auth("userid", "secret")
response = http.request(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `basic_auth` method is the right way of supplying a username and password, but only if the server is expecting that form of authentication. If, as your curl snippet suggests, it is expecting digest authentication then basic auth will indeed not work.

Net::HTTP does not have support for digest auth build in, however the [net-http-digest_auth](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-http-digest_auth) adds support for it. The gem includes some [example usage](http://docs.seattlerb.org/net-http-digest_auth/Net/HTTP/DigestAuth.html).

Comment: ya i did tried this...but when I tried in my console, it gave me error when i tried to do uri.user = 'username'
uri.password = 'password'

Answer (score 1):

There's an example of basic auth in my Ruby Net::HTTP cheat sheet: https://github.com/augustl/net-http-cheat-sheet/blob/master/basic_auth.rb

Posting the code here, for completeness:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://google.com/")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request.basic_auth("username", "password")
response = http.request(request)
```

This works for me. Perhaps you're talking to a non-standard server?

Comment: is this apply on digest auth?

Comment: Probably not, I've never used or heard about digest auth before, actually. Just skimmed the wikipedia article, seems like digest auth and basic auth are completely different beasts. Is the server you're talking to using digest or basic? You can tell by looking at the first word of the "WWW-Authenticate" header in the reply.

Comment: ya they are digest, so I'm trying to look into https://rubygems.org/gems/net-http-digest_auth, but it cant work as well

Comment: Seems like Ruby indeed doesn't come with digest auth built-in. You might want to update your question to make it clearer what exactly your problem is :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is : [**Net::HTTP**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-new) documented.

> Creates a new Net::HTTP object without opening a TCP connection or HTTP session.
>
> The address should be a DNS hostname or IP address, the port is the port the server operates on. If no port is given the default port for HTTP or HTTPS is used.
>
> If none of the p_ arguments are given, the proxy host and port are taken from the http_proxy environment variable (or its uppercase equivalent) if present. If the proxy requires authentication you must supply it by hand. See URI::Generic#find_proxy for details of proxy detection from the environment. To disable proxy detection set p_addr to nil.
>
> If you are connecting to a custom proxy, p_addr the DNS name or IP address of the proxy host, p_port the port to use to access the proxy, and **p_user and p_pass the username and password if authorization is required to use the proxy.**

Answer (score 0):

Going with **DigestAuth** ,you should do exactly is write on http://docs.seattlerb.org/net-http-digest_auth/Net/HTTP/DigestAuth.html requesting **twice**, because the second request (200) uses the first request error *header* (401). Check the `auth` variable:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/http/digest_auth'

digest_auth = Net::HTTP::DigestAuth.new

uri = URI.parse 'http://localhost:8000/'
uri.user = 'username'
uri.password = 'password'

h = Net::HTTP.new uri.host, uri.port

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri

res = h.request req
# FIRST REQUEST: res is a 401 response with a WWW-Authenticate header

auth = digest_auth.auth_header uri, res['www-authenticate'], 'GET'

# create a new request with the Authorization header
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
req.add_field 'Authorization', auth

# SECOND REQUEST: re-issue request with Authorization
res = h.request req
```